# Android button becomes small in Nexus 5

Tags: android, android-button, nexus-5

I am creating a button dynamically for a particular screen. It is clearly visible in Emulator where as looking very small in Device (Nexus 5).

In Emulator:

[image]

In Device:
[image]

I am using below code for button creation in code:

```
LayoutParams updt_btn_params = new LayoutParams();
update_data = new Button(this);
update_data.setText("Update");
update_data.setTextSize(9);
updt_btn_params.width=80;
updt_btn_params.height=45;
updt_btn_params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
update_data.setOnClickListener(update_listnr);
update_data.setLayoutParams(updt_btn_params);
```

What else I have to do for getting buttons clearly in Device. TIA

Comment: Mind that you are using **pixels** in code, instead of using **dp** (**sp** for fonts). Therefore, they aren't properly scaled.

Comment: Do I need to use like updt_btn_params.width=80dp; correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @kavuru, Yes, I think that is what Der Golem was trying to say, and use 9sp for your TextSize

Comment: The best way would be using a separate layout file for your ListView items. There you can define everything in **dp**, **sp**, ... As an alternative, you have to find the device scaling factor and multiply your values by that (see px to dp conversion). It may also help declaring your unit type as COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP and COMPLEX_UNIT_SP http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#COMPLEX_UNIT_SP

Comment: ok..so if we define in sp & dp with in layout  then does it scale it automatically as per device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using these:

```
updt_btn_params.width=80;
updt_btn_params.height=45;
```

With this you are setting the width and the height in pixels, which is something you should never do. Different devices have different pixel densities which means that the size of the pixels varies from device to device. The Nexus 5 has quite a high pixel density which makes your buttons very small.

*There a now 2 ways to get around this:*

**1. define the values in your dimen.xml in the resources**

In your resources there is a folder "values" that should contain a dimen.xml. In this you can define your dimensions for the Buttons like this:

```
<dimen name="width">80dp</dimen>
<dimen name="height">45dp</dimen>
```

Then you can read them into your code via:

```
updt_btn_params.width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.width);
updt_btn_params.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.height);
```

**2. use XML**

But if you can define the whole layout of your activity in an XML-file.

In there you can define the width and the height in "dp" like this:

```
layout_width="80dp"
layout_height="45dp"
```

It is essential to use "dp" instead of "px" to make the Buttons look exactly the same on every device.

Answer (score 0):

```
float ht_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, ht, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
float wt_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, wt, getResources()
```